# Is there a way to tell doxygen to not include a function in a call graph?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

The call graphs that are generated by doxygen end up including calls to functions that are of no particular meaning such as as logging utilities which clutters up the call graph. I was wondering whether there is a way to mark certain functions to not be included in the call graphs that would allow doxygen to produce useful call graphs.

Edit:
Forgot to specify that the graphs are being generated with CALL_GRAPH set to true so all the documented functions are generating call graphs.

Answer (score 0):

If these classes are really unimportant to your design, you can exclude them altogether with `EXCLUDE` or `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`.